# How to enforce type checking for dynamic component registration and prop validation in TypeScript React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have created a package, in this package, we have a global object `globalRegister` to store the `id <-> Component` mapping.

Developers can use `add(id, Comp)` function to register a new item to this global object. And use `show(id, props)` function to access the component with the props they want to inject.

When user call `show` function, I have two type checking want to achieve.

1. I want to check `id` has already exist in the globalRegister. If not, we should be able to see the red wavy line.
2. I want to check the props user input is compatible with `globalRegister[id]`

I think the second requirements is more important and hard to achieve. Can anyone give me some idea about how to implement this? Thanks!!

(Here is a simple use case example about my package and expectations I want to see)

```js
// Package's code
import React from 'react';
const globalRegister: Record<string, React.FC> = {}

const add = (id: string, Comp: React.FC<any>) => {
    globalRegister[id] = Comp
};

const show = (id: string, props?: Record<string, unknown>) => { 
    // ...
};

// Application's code
type Props1 = {age: number; name: string;}
const Comp1 = (props: Props1) => {
    return <></>
}

add('id_1', Comp1);

show('id_1', {age: 1, name: 'abc'}) // Correct
show('id_2') // Expect error, as we haven't register `id_2` to globalRegister 
show('id_1', {age: 1, name: 'abc', wrongProp: 'abc'}) // Expect error, as the second parameter is incompatible with Comp1's props
```

Comment: For your first requirement, you should implement it with actual code. Typescript won't do anything at runtime, so you need code logic to throw an error if `show()` is called with an invalid `id`. You're asking TS to understand how the code will execute, which it doesn't do. You need to implement these checks with actual code, which can definitely handle these requirements!